# "Crypto settings changed" message shown when launching an Azure Cloud Service locally

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

I’m getting the following behavior when I try to launch an Azure Cloud Service locally 
1)  Popup that the debugging environment is getting ready is shown (step1.jpg)
2)  Message “Your about to be signed out, crypto settings changed” is shown (step2.jpg)
3)  Force restart of the notebook is performed (step3.jpg)

This is happening constantly in both debug and start without debugging options.
I tried changing the properties of the azure cloud service but it didn’t help. I also tried to use the internet what does this message mean and could not find any relevant data. appreciate ANY help. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you tried to share some screenshots but they are not showing up here. Can you try adding the screenshots again?
Also, please share the steps you are following or the link of the doc you are referring to.
This article on debugging cloud service on Visual studio might be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines?view=vs-2017 Thanks.

Comment: Any update?....

Comment: Any updates on this?  I'm having the same issue, you cannot get a screenshot since the computer reboots immediately after you try to run the cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

Check you ServiceDefinition.csdef for startup tasks. I think you maybe running the DisableSslv3.cmd script on your local machine causing it to force a restart. Just comment out the line while debugging locally.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @user2282308, I would say that in a more global approach, it worth to check the startup tasks in the serviceDefinition.csdef and verify that all tasks are executed as "expected".

@user22822308 spoke about DisableSslv3.cmd, but on my side, the issue was that the script [runTLSsettings.cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/applications-dont-support-tls-1-2) should be executed only when running on Azure service (this script ends with a reboot of the machine and the famous "crypto settings changed")

This is the serviceDefinition.csdef integration that is proposed by Microsoft for the runTLSSettings script:

```
<Startup> 
    <Task executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" commandLine="RunTLSSettings.cmd"> 
    </Task> 
</Startup>
```

This is ok when debugging your cloud service in Visual Studio 2019, but as soon as you try to debug with Visual Studio 2022 you will receive the "Crypto settings changed".

My feeling is that the startup task is **not done** in VS 2019 meanwhile it is **done in VS 2022**.
Thus, what is missing is the definition of the environment variable that indicate to runTLSSettings script if we are running on emulator or not.

The environment variable definition is well explained in this other microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks#environment-variables

At the end, this is the correct csdef:

```
<Startup>
<Task commandLine="runTLSSettings.cmd" executionContext="limited" taskType="simple">
    <Environment>
        <Variable name="ComputeEmulatorRunning">
            <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
        </Variable>

    </Environment>
</Task>
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens every single time I run Visual Studio without elevated privilege's.  When I start debugging the cloud service and the azure emulator starts, I get this message and the computer reboots.